# Add a custom matcher in Jasmine 1.3 - shows undefined

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor, end-to-end

I'm using protractor with jasmine 1.3, tried adding a custom matcher to my spec using the example [here](http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html)

```
    beforeEach(function () {
        utils.log("beforeEach");

        this.addMatchers({
            toBeGoofy: function (expected) {

                if (expected === undefined) {
                    expected = '';
                }
                var pass = this.actual.hyuk === "gawrsh" + expected;
                if (pass) {
                    this.message = "Expected " + this.actual + " not to be quite so goofy";
                } else {
                    this.message = "Expected " + this.actual + " to be goofy, but it was not very goofy";
                }

                return pass;
            },
        });
    });
```

note that I didn't change anything from their example.
after that, i try using it inside an "it" like that:

```
expect({ "hyuk": "j" }).toBeGoofy();
```

and i get an error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

on the line that the matcher was used on..
any help?

Comment: Where have you placed the `beforeEach()` block? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe tried in several places, before the first "it", before the first "describe", the spec is very simply structured: 3 "it"s in one describe.
also the log function there works and prints as expected...

Comment: Are you sure you are using jasmine v1.3 ? You usually get this error if you use a newer version of jasmine. Latest one is v2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the matcher definition apparently.
instead of:

```
if (pass) {
    this.message = "Expected " + this.actual + " not to be quite so goofy";
    } else {
    this.message = "Expected " + this.actual + " to be goofy, but it was not very goofy";
}
```

this message should be an array of 2 messages, first for pass, second for not.matcher so it would be something like this:

```
this.message = function() {
    return [
        "Expected " + this.actual.hyuk + " to be gawrsh",
        "Expected " + this.actual.hyuk + " not to be gawrsh"
    ];
};
```